# Font shorthand not working in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, fonts, shorthand

I try to shorten my css with shorthands. In my paragraph code i have:

```
p{
font: 12px/14px normal 'verdana';
margin: 0px;
}
```

This works fine in chrome, safari ect but not in firefox. It does not register "font: 12px/14px normal 'verdana';" only "margin: 0px;"

What is the problem/what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

It should be: Font: Weight, Size, Family

```
    p{
    font:normal 12px/14px  'verdana';
    margin: 0px;
    }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4tUxp/

Comment: You should probably also capitalise 'verdana'.

Comment: Capitalization is not needed in practice, though in principle, font family names *may* be case-sensitive.

Comment: In fact, Chrome and Safari get this wrong: by mandatory error processing rules of CSS, the malformed `font` declaration shall be ignored. IE 9+ seems to get this wrong in its own way: it parses the rule in the question so that the `font-family` value is `normal "verdana"` and apparently interprets this as the browser’s default font (whereas IE 8 and older get things right here!).